# No two adjacent bulbs on

Tags: probability, combinatorics, puzzle

The problem is to count number of configuration of $9$ bulbs on a $3\times 3$ grid, where no two bulbs that are adjacent are switched on.

I solved this problem in a very ad-hoc kind of manner, the answer is $63$, here's how

(I am representing configuration row wise as : $\mathtt{row_1}$, $\mathtt{row_2}$, $\mathtt{row_3}$)

These are the only unique configurations of the bulbs
$101|010|101$ or $010|101|010$ or $100|001|100$ * 4(depending on the $4$ possible position of 2nd row bulb on middle cell of every boundary) or $100|001|010$ * 4 (depending on the position of row 1 bulb on corners)

So a total of $2^5 + (2^4-1) + 4\times 1 + (2^2-1)\times 4$ (subtraction is done to ensure no double counting)

My question is, is there a more systematic way of solving this problem ?

Comment: The one-dimensional version of this problem has a nice recursive solution that lets you conclude that the number of configurations is equal to a corresponding Fibonacci number. However, getting a recursive characterization of the number of configurations seems very tricky here

Comment: Whatever systematic approach exists for $n \times n$ grids, I suspect that it won't be any more efficient for the $3 \times 3$ case than what you did.

Comment: You can get some information at [OEIS A006506](https://oeis.org/A006506).

Comment: For 3x3 I would have used a different counting method - for each possible middle row, count the possibilities for the outer rows. This gives $5^2+2\cdot 3^2+4^2+2^2=63$. I don't know of any way that generalises to $n\times n$. For a fixed width, say $n\times 3$ there is recursive formula you could work out, but this gets more complicated the larger the width.